# How to detect WindowsService properties changes?

Tags: c#, events, service, windows-services

How to detect change of the `ServiceStartMode` property in `WindowsService`?
At start is `Automatic`, but later someone change it to `Manual` - how to catch this event?

Answer (score 1):

You can't detect a change of service StartMode as there are no events linked to that particular situazion... however, using System.Management features you can at any time check the current StartMode of a service and eventually change it. Please, have a look at [this very good snippet](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28161/Using-WMI-to-manipulate-services-Install-Uninstall) which implements a full features class which allow you to manipulate this.